# intersection of two sets in two coloumn of different table In Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

i have two table both have a column with comma(,) separated multiple values. i want to fetch rows from first table which have at least a single match in both the multiple column.
Tables Are
First Table
[image]

Second Table
[image]

like first row in first column has 3 and first row in second table has 3 means its a match so first row of first table should be fetch.
HoW To write a query for that

Comment: Please explain more. What are *all* the values you expect?

Comment: Afaik, it is not possible to do this with good performance. You should try to fix your schema.

Comment: could you possible try this Select servicecode from second_table where INSTR(servicecode, 
(select SUBSTRING_INDEX(servicecode, ',', 1) from firstTable)) > 0 in mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the performance of such a query could go,

but then you could try something like this:

```
SELECT firsttable.servicecode                          AS a, 
       Substring_index(firsttable.servicecode, ',', 1) AS x 
FROM   firsttable 
      JOIN secondtable 
         ON Locate(( Substring_index(firsttable.servicecode, ',', 1) ), 
             secondtable.servicecode) > 0
```

[Working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91780/31)

P.S: this is in mysql.